# como soluciono este error:cannot dynamic_cast

Tags: c++

tengo un arreglo de mascotas pueden ser perros o gatos y quiero sacar una en concreto lo estoy intentando de esta manera

```
const DtPerro *Unperro = dynamic_cast<const DtPerro*>(&mascotas[j]);

const DtGato *Ungato = dynamic_cast<const DtGato*>(&mascotas[j]);
```

y luego consulto con un "if" que tipo de mascota había en la posicion "j" del arreglo de mascotas,pero me sale este mega error,algunas sugerencias?

```
 error: cannot dynamic_cast '(mascotas + ((sizetype)(((unsigned int)j) * 4)))' (of type 'const class DtMascota**') to type 'const class DtGato*' (source is not a pointer to class)
```

Comment: `c0nst` o `const`?

Answer (score 4):

El error es muy claro:

> cannot dynamic_cast '...' (of type 'const class DtMascota**') to type 'const class DtGato*' (source is not a pointer to class)

Te está diciendo que no puedes hacer un *cast* de un `DtMascota **` (puntero-a-puntero) hacia un `const class DtGato *` (puntero).

No muestras lo que es tu variable `mascotas[]`, pero seguro que es del tipo

```
DtMascota *mascotas[];
```

Y tú estás intentando hacer un *cast* de la expresión `&mascotas[j]`, lo cual es, efectivamente, un puntero-a-puntero y no es posible hacer un `dynamic_cast` de eso.

Cambia tu código a

```
const DtPerro *Unperro = dynamic_cast< const DtPerro * >( mascotas[j] );

const DtGato *Ungato = dynamic_cast< const DtGato * >( mascotas[j] );
```

Comment: gracias amigo,problema resuelto :)